# Add setSuppressesIncrementalRendering property to UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, properties, uiwebview

Trying to get my feet wet with a very simple UIWebView iPhone app. I've got the following code in ViewController.m:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://mysite.com/";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I want to add the setSuppressesIncrementalRendering property to this UIWebView but I'm new to Objective C. Any pointers?

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
[webView setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:YES];
```